# Really weird Cookie header behaviour? - Cookies

Tags: python, django, http, cookies, http-headers

I'm using Firefox 3.6.8 for these tests.

**I'm setting a cookie within the response headers** of my web app using:

```
Set-Cookie: session=7878dfdsfjsdf89sd89f8df9
```

This **does not seem to override** the session Cookie.

---

When a request is performed instead Firefox even sends **duplicate cookies**:

```
Cookie: session=7d75cd8f55895cbccb0d31ee07c7afc0; 
        session=671e8448a5cebda0442005a186cf69a3; 
        4cb6f2d75c9ffc8916cb55bcbaafecd8
```

---

**What is going on??
Any ideas would be great!! =)**

---

This is quite disastrous in my case... if someone could explain what's going on it would really help me out!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't specify the path or domain for a cookie when setting it, it defaults to the current path and current hostname.  If you then go ahead and try setting the same cookie name from a URL with a different path or hostname, it will add a new cookie instead of replacing the old one.

I suspect what you want to do is just set a cookie with a global path for your site and for your entire domain.  So something like this:

```
Set-Cookie: session=7878dfdsfjsdf89sd89f8df9; path=/; domain=.mysite.com
```

Comment: I think you have solved my problem... I was literally going crazy =D

Comment: can I set the Cookie to cover all paths?

Comment: Yes, setting a path to just / will cover all paths on your site

Answer (score 3):

You can delete the previous cookie using the [response](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects) object.

```
response.delete_cookie(cookie_key)
```

The set of cookies is available via the [request](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#attributes) object in the `request.COOKIES` dictionary, and you can obtain the key from there.

Since you're using Django, here's how you might do this in the view function:

```
def my_view(request):
    # do some work and create a response object
    response = HttpResponse(some_content)

    # first delete any previously set cookie named "session"
    if 'session' in request.COOKIES:
        response.delete_cookie('session')

    # set the new cookie
    response.set_cookie('session', <cookie value goes here>')
    return response
```

Comment: thanks, how do I get an http server to replace the Cookie though? I won't have control over the user's machine when a web app goes live.

Comment: btw I'm sending in the 'Set-Cookie' in manually through Django, but Firefox will not replace the old cookies no matter what...

Comment: This is will make my hair go grey before time =)

Comment: RadiantHex, see the update for how you might do this on the server side in a django view.